# Improving the Restricted Source tag

Tags: discussion, tags

[restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) is a fairly popular tag with just about 200 questions at the time of posting.  It also has a pretty minimal description:

> Imposes a restriction on the source code used to solve the challenge, for example, having no numbers in the source code.

While short tag description can have a lot of benefits I have been noticing a good deal of low quality or problematic questions tagged with restricted source lately.  So I thought it might be time to talk about what makes a [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) problem good and bad and what we can do to help people make good challenges with this tag.

So, what does it mean to be a good restricted source question?

Answer (score 7):

## Restricted Source should be program verifiable

A source restriction should be verifiable by a computer, otherwise a question is unclear and should be closed.  If it cannot be checked by a computer, it is likely not actually a restriction on the source of the program but on something else. (like the algorithm implemented or the programming language chosen)

How does this apply to questions currently tagged with [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source)?

In my mind there are three types of [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) challenges.

- Restricting operations:

  These questions ban a type of operation, such as addition or for loops.

  [Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20996/add-without-addition-or-any-of-the-4-basic-arithmetic-operators)
- Banning characters:

  These type of questions give a list of characters that you are not allowed to use in your program.

  [Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world)
- Patterned requirements:

  These questions require the entire source code to follow pattern or structure specified in the question.

  [Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58556/just-repeat-yourself)

  [Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88806/only-even-bytes)

  [Example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108133/three-three-three)

The first one is unenforceable.  If you ban addition is incrementation allowed? If you ban loops is recursion allowed?  These kinds of restrictions cannot be checked by a computer and human checkers might even disagree.  These are *not* restricted source questions and should be closed as unclear.

The second type are a little better and by far the most popular of the three types. For a single encoding it is not very hard to write a program to check if answers follow the restriction.  For other encodings it might be harder and there might be room for interpretation or disagreement but overall it is clear and [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source).  These are however *boring*.  We see a lot of implement a trivial task without these characters and they are no longer novel and should be discouraged in the tag wiki.

The third type of [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source) challenges, the patterned type, are the most interesting of the bunch, they are often verifiable regardless of the encoding.  These challenges are what we should promote as the use of [restricted-source](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-source).

Comment: How do you categorise challenges in which a program has to fail/change behaviour under certain types of mutation (the opposite of [tag:radiation-hardening])? (This is a restriction commonly used as a method of banning comments.) Is that [tag:restricted-source] at all?

Comment: @ais523 I was not familiar with these prior.  In my opinion these are not [tag:restricted-source] but I am not an expert in this area.

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11197/8478)